# Laravel CRUD ORM Can't find model

Tags: php, laravel, orm, relationship, crud

I have been trying to associate a User with a Profile.
Here is my code:

Profile Model:

```
class Profile extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

User Model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable

{
  ...
    public function profile(){
        return $this->hasOne('App/Profile');
    }
}
```

ProfileController:

```
public function show($username)
    {
        $user = User::where('username',$username)->first();
        $profile = $user->profile;
        return view('profiles.show')->withProfile($profile);
    }
```

Route (It's meant to be "profil"):

```
Route::resource('profil','ProfileController');
```

Error:
http://prntscr.com/ff6y0a

Any tips on doing the rest of the CRUD functionality is very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `App/Profile` to `App\Profile` in your `User` model relationship.